# Hiding cells by using VBA

Tags: excel, hide, vba

I am using the following code to hide the required cells in Excel VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell   As Range
    Set Cell = Range("$F$26")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("F26").Value < 2 Then
            Rows("39:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Range("F26").Value < 3 Then
            Rows("47:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Range("F26").Value < 4 Then
            Rows("55:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else: Rows("39:61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It works perfectly when I put values in the descending order (like 4, 3, 2, 1). But after putting 1, if I am plan to switch to 2 or 3 (but not 4). Then it doesn't show the cells in second and third panel group. But if I put 4, then it again shows all panel groups. I attached the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to re-evaluate subsequent calls with new values in Range("$F$26") from scratch; e.g. make everything visible and then decide what gets hidden.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F26"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Rows("39:61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Select Case Range("F26").Value
            Case Is < 2
                Rows("39:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 2
                Rows("47:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 3
                Rows("55:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I've changed your condition evaluation to a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) and removed the `Cell` variable as unnnecessary.

I could not find any contingency for when Range("F26") was blank. Currently, that falls under the `< 2` condition.